# Deploy to Heroku staging, then production with Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jenkins

I have a Rails application with a Jenkinsfile which I'd like to set up so that a build is first deployed to staging, then if I am happy with the result, it can be built on production.

I've set up 2 Heroku instances, `myapp-staging` and `myapp-production`.

My Jenkinsfile has a node block that look like:

```
node {
  currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
  setBuildStatus("Build started", "PENDING");

  try {
    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout scm
      gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
      shortCommit = gitCommit.take(7)
    }

    stage('Build') {
      parallel 'build-image':{
        sh "docker build -t ${env.BUILD_TAG} ."
      }, 'run-test-environment': {
        sh "docker-compose --project-name myapp up -d"
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      ansiColor('xterm') {
        sh "docker run -t --rm --network=myapp_default -e DATABASE_HOST=postgres ${env.BUILD_TAG} ./ci/bin/run_tests.sh"
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy - Staging') {
      // TODO. Use env.BRANCH_NAME to make sure we only deploy from staging
      withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'Heroku Git Login', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
         sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@git.heroku.com/myapp-staging.git staging')
      }
      setBuildStatus("Staging build complete", "SUCCESS");
    }

    stage('Sanity check') {
      steps {
        input "Does the staging environment look ok?"
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy - Production') {
      // TODO. Use env.BRANCH_NAME to make sure we only deploy from master
      withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'Heroku Git Login', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
       sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@git.heroku.com/myapp-production.git HEAD:refs/heads/master')
    }
    setBuildStatus("Production build complete", "SUCCESS");
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the correct way to do this or is there some other best practice? For example do I need two Jenkins pipelines for this or is one project pipeline enough?
2. How can I use Jenkins' BRANCH_NAME variable to change dynamically depending on the stage I'm at?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

for the first question, using one Jenkinsfile to describe the complete project pipeline is desirable. it keeps the description of the process all in one place, and shows you the process flow in one UI, so your Jenkinsfile seems great in that regard.

for the second question, you can wrap steps in `if` conditions based on branch. so if you wanted to, say, skip the prod deployment and the step that asks the user if staging looks ok (since you're not going to do the prod deployment) if the branch is not master, this would work.

```
node('docker') {
  try {
    stage('Sanity check') {
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        input "Does the staging environment look ok?"
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy - Production') {
      echo 'deploy check'
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        echo 'do prod deploy stuff'
      }
    }
  } catch(error) {
  }
}
```

i removed some stuff from your pipeline that wasn't necessary to demonstrate the idea, but i also fixed what looked to me like two issues. 1) you seemed to be mixing metaphors between scripted and declarative pipelines. i think you are trying to use a scripted pipeline, so i made it full scripted. that means you cannot use `steps`, i think. 2) your `try` was missing a `catch`.

at the end of the day, the UI is a bit weird with this solution, since all steps will always show up in all cases, and they will just show as green, like they passed and did what they said they would do (it will look like it deployed to prod, even on non-master branches). there is no way around this with scripted pipelines, to my knowledge. with declarative pipelines, you can do the same conditional logic with `when`, and the UI (at least the blue ocean UI) actually understands your intent and shows it differently.

have fun!

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788529/jenkins-pipeline-to-deploy-on-heroku?